# Trouble Sending Messages from Content Script to Popup in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension using React, TypeScript, and Webpack. In my content script (contentScript.tsx), I'm extracting data from a webpage upon the DOM load and attempting to send this data as a message to my popup.tsx to display it on the extension UI.

```
//contentscript.ts
    (async () => {
      // ... (data extraction logic)
    
      const profileInfo = {
        userName: linkedinName || upworkName || twitterName || null,
        profileUrl: window.location.href.split("?")[0],
      };
    
      const response = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        greeting: "hello",
        type: "profile_name",
        profileInfo,
      });
    
      console.log(response); // This logs properly when sending to background.ts, but not to popup.tsx
    })();
```

In my popup.tsx, I'm attempting to listen for this message:

```
 // popup.tsx
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
        console.log("hit here");
        if (request.type === "profile_name") {
          setUserInfo(request.profileInfo);
          const { userName } = request.profileInfo;
        }
    });
```

The issue is that I'm not receiving the message in popup.tsx, although it works when sending to background.ts. Can anyone provide guidance on how to properly send messages from a content script to a popup in a Chrome extension using React?

Comment: The popup runs only when shown, so if it's hidden when your content script runs, the message will be lost. You can extract the data at the start of the popup script [using executeScript](/a/67227376) instead of using `content_scripts`.

Comment: @wOxxOm got it. thanks